# How to detect if a link has been clicked, even though the page is redirected

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create a menu bar which will retain the info about which menu was clicked by changing the background color of that menu.

```
<div class="dashboard_navigation">
    {% for header in headers %}
             <div class="navigation_header" name="Home">
                <a id='a' href="{{ header.url }}">{{ header.name }}</a>

                <div class="navigation_subheader">

                        {% for subheader in subheaders %}
                            {% if header.id == subheader.parent.id %}
                                <div>
                                    <a href="{{ subheader.url }}" >{{ subheader.name }}</a> 
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                </div>  
             </div>     
    {% endfor %}
```

The script I am using is as follows

```
    $(".navigation_header").live('click', function()
    {           
         $(this).children('a').css("background-color","red");

    });
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the info provided in the question enough or should I add something?

Comment: What if I got there not because I clicked a link, but because I went to the URL directly? The server should build and highlight the navigation, based on the current page the user is on. It's not really a job for JavaScript.

Comment: `"should I add something"` -- Yes, if you show so much server code, tag the question appropriately.  I've added the ASP tag in this case, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link the page is going to be redirected so even if you attached a click event handler to its parent `div` it is not going to work as the page will be redirected.

You can store which link is click in a `cookie` for the current user session. Read the cookie value on page load and set the background color accordingly.

You can take a look at jquery cookie plugin here
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Answer (score 0):

Each `div.navigation_header` has a unique name, like "*Home*", right? (If they *don't* then give them one!)

Your server should also know which page corresponds with each name.  So, it will write a style just for that page.

For example, for the ***Home*** page, it would write:

```
div.navigation_header[name=Home] a {
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

Otherwise, you would have to use cookies or URL parameters.